# how to rsync files and keep files that have been deleted in the source?

Tags: linux

I was trying to see if its possible to rsync a bunch of files from a website but, if the website deleted files, I don't want rsync to delete those files on my end and keep them.

currently as a starting point I'm doing:
```rsynch -av "link" /repo/

how do I make sure that files that were deleted in the link do not delete when I rsync the repo for updates?

Comment: `rsync` does not delete by default. You have to request that in a specific manner using the `--delete` switch. Check the `rsync` manual page as a reference: `man rsync`

Comment: A) This site is about programming problems. B) Did you consider running rsync -h; or just search the net? Such things are documented a **zillion** times.

Comment: I did and I did not find anything.

Answer (score 1):

rsync does not delete by default. You have to request that in a specific manner using the --delete switch. Check the rsync manual page as a reference: man rsync

@arkascha